# How to change login details in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server

Firstly I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 and configured to use windows authentication mode. I have changed my computer name and Network domain. After changing the computer name I can't access the database with the new user. It displays an error that says

> cannot connect to elias-laptop\sqlexpress.

The operating system I am using is Windows XP. How can I regain access to the database?

Comment: It's been a while since I've installed MSSQL, but isn't it mandatory to specify a password for the `sa` user during installation? If so, you should still be able to login with that user.

Comment: @Stijn no it isn't and its usually disabled because it weakens security

Comment: It seems it might be the server name in your connection string more so than log in details, based on the error message and if what you have changed is computer name.

Comment: Both servername and instance of SQL Server you are trying to connect to. the default instance name for the full blown SQL server is just simply (local) or ".". For SQL Server express it is \SQLExpress, as your connection string seems to be point to right now... you seem to be connecting to the wrong SQL Server instance

Comment: @user1472289 1) Did you update the connection string? Try `.\sqlexpress`.  Did you try to open the database using a local Administrator account? 2) Never do that again. You are now trying to connect to a database with an unknown user, from an unknown domain.

Comment: Try `localhost\sqlexpress`. If you have SqlServer Management Studio you should be able to locate the instances on your system. Am not familiar with XP anymore, but if you can get to "Component Services" or just "Services", and find SQL Server, you should be able to get the instance name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
MSDN Blogs > Raul Garcia's blog > [Disaster Recovery: What to when the SA account password is lost in SQL Server 2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/07/12/disaster-recovery-what-to-do-when-the-sa-account-password-is-lost-in-sql-server-2005.aspx)

In the comments section Raul Garcia says "This feature was introduced in SQL Server 2005, and it works for SQL Server 2005, 2008 & 2008R2."

This has screen pictures: Gert Van Gorp > [How to recover SA password on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2](http://v-consult.be/2011/05/26/recover-sa-password-microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2/).